# Dividing longs which are returned by method - wrong values

Tags: java, overflow, primitive-types

I have two methods: power and factorial:

```
public static long pow(int x, int n) {
    long p = x;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        p *= x;
    }
    return p;
}

public static long fact(int n) {
    long s = n;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++ ) {
        s *= i;
    }
    return s;
}
```

that are returning *longs*. When I want to use them in new method evaluating [Exponential function](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/math/c/f/5/cf5d03795de766b013f91c4cb409bd9c.png) i get wrong results comparing to Math.exp(x). My code:

```
public static void exp(int x, double eps) {
    int i = 1;
    double pow = 1.0;
    double fact = 1.0;
    double sum = 0.0;
    double temp;
    do {
        temp = pow/fact;
        sum += temp;
        pow = pow(x, i);
        fact = fact(i);
        i++;
    }
    while (temp > eps);
    System.out.println("Check: " + Math.exp(x));
    System.out.println("My: " + sum);
}

public static void main() {
    int x = 10;
    double eps = 0.0000000000001;

    exp(x, eps);
}
```

and the output for x=10 is:

> Check: 22026.465794806718
>
> My: 21798.734894914145

the larger x, the bigger "loss of precision" (not exactly, because you can't really call it precise...).

The twist is, when methods **power** and **factorial** return **double** then the output is correct. Can anyone explain me how to make it work?

Methods *pow* and *fact* must return long and I must use them in *exp* (college assignment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try this pow method:

```
public static long pow(int x, int n) {
    long p = x;
    System.out.println("Pow: "+x+","+n);
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        p *= x;
        System.out.println(p);
    }
    return p;
}
```

You get this output:

```
...
Pow: 10,20
100
1000
10000
...
...
1000000000000000
10000000000000000
100000000000000000
1000000000000000000
-8446744073709551616
7766279631452241920
```

The long value overflows: `10^20` is just too big to fit in a long.

> Methods *pow* and *fact* must return long and I must use them in *exp* (college assignment).

Then there is not much you can do to fix it. You could throw an exception if `eps` is too small.

Comment: Well, wow, You are right. It is kind of weird for me that `long` has smaller range in this case than `double` which behaves properly... Thank you.

Comment: @hodak - What do you mean? long has smaller range (~ 2^63) than double (~ 2^1023).

Comment: Both the functions overflow, depending on size of parameters - the pow() grows faster.
You can use BigDecimal and detect the situation but youcan hardly fit the result in long.

Answer (score 0):

Long data types can't handle decimal precision that's why you're values are wrong with long.  Why don't you just have the functions return the double values?

**Edit:** Heres what I came up with:

```
  public static long pow(int x, int n) 
  {
    double p = x;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
      p *= x;
    }
    return (long)p;
  }

  public static long fact(int n) 
  {
    double s = n;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++ ) {
      s *= i;
    }
    return (long)s;
  }


  public static void exp(int x, double eps) 
  {
    double pow = 1.0;
    double fact = 1.0;
    double sum = 0.0;
    double temp;
    for(int ii=1; ii < 100; ii++)
    {
      pow = pow(x, ii);
      fact = fact(ii);
      temp = (double)pow/(double)fact;
      temp = temp == 1 ? 0 : temp;
      sum += temp;
    }

    System.out.println("Check: " + Math.exp(x));
    System.out.println("My: " + sum);
  }

  public static void main(final String[] args)
  {
    int x = 10;
    double eps = 0.0000000000001;

    exp(x, eps);
  }
```

That's about the closest you're going to get without using the decimals.

```
Check: 22026.465794806718
My: 21946.785573087538
```

Comment: I can't, it's said in my assignment to use longs. But I wasn't able to cast them too, when I was trying to do it like this: 'pow = (double)power(x, i)' and 'fact = (double)fact(i)'

Comment: @hodak it seems very weird that you can't use doubles in the assignment, are you sure thats correct?

Comment: Yes, he specifically declared that, but it is possible that he did this to force us to find the answer why that's not correct. Good teacher, this took me only about couple of hours ;)

Answer (score 0):

How large is `x` typically? It could be integer overflow. Try changing all the `int` arguments in `pow` and `fact` to be `long` instead.

Comment: x isn't large, it's from 1 to, say, 20. Changing `int`s to `long`s didn't help.